# New to perl; getting some errors I'm not sure about

Tags: perl

I can't seem to figure out why I'm getting this error when trying to run my .pl script.

Here is the script:

```
# mini script for creating diff files in a single directory

# directory of patch files
$patchDir = "c:\oc\Patch Files";

if ($#ARGV != 1 && $#ARGV != 2)
{
    print "Usage: diff <file name> [-s]\n";
    print "Example:  \n";
    print "   |Diff relative to Index (staged)|  :  diff MOM00123456_1.patch \n";
    print "   |Diff Staged|                      :  diff MOM00123456_1.patch -s \n";
    exit;
}

$fileName = $ARGV[0];

if ($#ARGV == 2)
    $stagedArg = $ARGV[1];

if ($stagedArg)
    if ($stagedArg == "-s" || $stagedArg == "-S")
        system("git diff --staged --full-index > $fileName $patchDir");
    else
    {
        print "Unknown argument:  $stagedArg\n";
        exit;
    }
else
    system("git diff --full-index > $fileName $patchDir");
```

Test:

> diff.pl test.patch -s

Output:

> Scalar found where operator expected at C:\utils\diff.pl line 18, near
>
> ")
>
> $stagedArg"
>
> (Missing operator before $stagedArg?) syntax error at C:\utils\diff.pl line 18, near ")
>
> $stagedArg " syntax error at C:\utils\diff.pl line 21, near ")
>
> if" Execution of C:\utils\diff.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
>
> Execution of C:\utils\diff.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Can someone shed some light?

Comment: Don't write Perl scripts without `use strict;` and `use warnings;`.

Comment: String comparison id done with `eq` not with `==`.

Comment: @Quentin, he would get the same, newbie-cryptic, error message using strict and warnings. Is Perl really looking for "an operator" there? Or is it looking for a *brace* (or *block*)?

Comment: The perl compiler doesn't handle C code very well

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perl `if` syntax is:

```
if (condition) {
    statements;
}
```

You can't omit the curly braces.

---

You might find `use diagnostics;` useful. Given a simple test script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;
if (1) 
    print 1;
```

We get:

```
syntax error at - line 5, near ") 
    print"
Execution of - aborted due to compilation errors (#1)
```

> (F) Probably means you had a syntax error.  Common reasons include:
>
> - A keyword is misspelled.
> - A semicolon is missing.
> - A comma is missing.
> - An opening or closing parenthesis is missing.
> - **An opening or closing brace is missing.**
> - A closing quote is missing.
>
> Often there will be another error message associated with the syntax
>   error giving more information.  (Sometimes it helps to turn on -w.)
>   The error message itself often tells you where it was in the line when
>   it decided to give up.  Sometimes the actual error is several tokens
>   before this, because Perl is good at understanding random input.
>   Occasionally the line number may be misleading, and once in a blue moon
>   the only way to figure out what's triggering the error is to call
>   perl -c repeatedly, chopping away half the program each time to see
>   if the error went away.  Sort of the cybernetic version of 20 questions.

```
Uncaught exception from user code:
    syntax error at - line 5, near ") 
        print"
    Execution of - aborted due to compilation errors.
```